# WPF Cannot locate resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a resource file and two views. This views use a resource file

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Dictionary1.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

And it will work while i dont put one view to the another. In this case i get this error

> Cannot locate resource 'dictionary1.xaml'

How to fix it?

Comment: More details please, where exactly is your dictionary? what do you mean by putting one inside another?

Comment: There are some styles for test. I mean that view1 have some view2 like a childs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Dictionary1.xaml` in your project's rootpath, remove '/' before Dictionary1

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
```

Or you can use packuri like :

```
 /yourAssemblyName;component/Dictionary1.xaml
```

Comment: To be precise, it's the _assembly name_, not the _namespace_ and the leading forward slash seems optional...

Comment: This is still the case in VS2015.  I got an error about a user control not finding a resource dictionary file in my project root folder, when I named it with a leading forward slash `/resourcedictionary.xaml`.  Why does this cause error messages, considering that it runs fine?

Answer (score 10):

Use [Pack Uri's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Assembly_Name;component/Dictionary1.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me, yet Microsoft doesn't list it in examples. Regular paths would work fine the application, but design mode and the IDE complain with errors.