# RibbonSplitButton cannot locate resource

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `RibbonSplitButton` that contains a `SmallImageSource` like so:

```
<UserControl x:Class="myProgram/toolbars/MainToolbar">
    <RibbonSplitButton SmallImageSource="/Images/Undo.png"/>
    <!-- more buttons-->
</UserControl>
```

I try to use this in another file (`main`):

```
<UserControl x:Class="myProgram/main"
             xmlns:toolbar="clr-namespace:myProgram.toolbars">
    <toolbar:MainToolbar/>
</UserControl>
```

I get the error message in `main`:

> Cannot locate resource 'images/undo.png'

However, when I switch to a normal button:

```
<Button>
    <Image Style="{StaticResource buttonstyle}">
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="40" UriSource="/Images/Undo.png"/>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</Button>
```

the error is gone.  I have tried using [Pack URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27814645/6538434), changing the **Build Action** to **[Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11948876/6538434)** and **Embedded Resource**, as well as **Clean Soultion**, **Rebuild Solution**, **Restarting Visual Studios** (rinse and repeat).  I image this has something to do with the `RibbonSplitButton`'s image source, but I have no idea.  The program runs fine (the `Undo.png` image shows and works perfectly), it's just annoying to have the error in my developer.  Anyone have suggests on how to get rid of the error?  (Note, this is a simplified folder structure, for example purposes).

**EDIT**
For anyone who ends up here at some point in the future, I found that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51643520/6538434) worked.

Comment: I have tried creating a project and using `<RibbonSplitButton SmallImageSource="/Images/Undo.png"/>` and it works fine for me. The build action on the file is Resource.

Comment: Sorry, @Ove, I forgot to mention the error is in another file.  I have updated my question to represent the error better.